# Javascript I cannot stop the execution of a Promise

Tags: javascript, promise

I am runnig the code below in a .ts file in the Next API Folder.
I am trying to wait the result of a call to an unofficial API of Reverso (https://www.npmjs.com/package/reverso-api).
The problem is that the code below continues to wait the request even if the the response from reverso has arrived and the value has been updated.
How can I can I do?
The `reverso.getContext('Dog', 'English', 'German', ... )`  method returns a Promise.

```
type Data = {
   responseWord : string
}

let r = 3;

export default async function handler( req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse<Data>) {

   const Reverso = require('reverso-api');
   const reverso = new Reverso();

   console.log("1");
   await reverso.getContext('Dog', 'English', 'German', (response : any) => {
       r = response?.text;
       console.log(r);
       return;
   }).catch((err : any) => {

   });
   console.log("2");

   res.status(200).json({ responseWord : `${r}` });
}
```

Comment: If reverso.getContext() returns a Promise, why are you passing a callback to it?

Comment: your ```console.log(r);``` has been executed, isn't ?

Comment: Here's the proper way to do this with a callback function: https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-lumiere-xwt9y?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Seems like the API offered by this library is odd in the first place, with a mix of callbacks and promises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reverso.getContext()` can be used in both ways, by using the callback based approach, or using promises, since it returns a promise. The correct way to retrieve the response data using an async function is this:

```
const Reverso = require('reverso-api');
const reverso = new Reverso();

export default async function handler( req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse<Data>) {
  try {
   const { text } = await reverso.getContext('Dog', 'English', 'German');
   res.status(200).json({ responseWord : `${text}` });
  } catch(e){
      console.log(e)
  }
}
```

The callback based version:

```
const Reverso = require('reverso-api');
const reverso = new Reverso();

export default function handler( req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse<Data>) : void  {
 reverso.getContext('Dog', 'English', 'German', (response : any) => {
     res.status(200).json({ responseWord : response?.text });
   }).catch((err : any) => {
     console.log(err)
   });
}
```

Comment: Taking a callback but still returning a promise for `.catch()` error handling? That's a weird API!

Comment: @Bergi that's exactly what i thought when I read the README file ;-), probably too lazy to set the err in the callback params...